# LED : Multiplexing : Color-mixing (RGB)

Tags: led, pwm, multiplexer, rgb, color

With a single RGB (red-green-blue) LED, if:

- Enabling the colors non-simultaneously (via multiplexing or a similar form of PWM),
- At a frequency which is sufficiently-high to make flicker indiscernible,

  - `f.cycle.minimum   ≥ 0200 [Hz]`
  - `f.cycle.practical ≥ 1000 [Hz]`

Would the alternating colors appear as mixed as if they were lit simultaneously?

### Example

Would:

- 33% Cycle: Red  only, then
- 33% Cycle: Blue only, then
- 34% Cycle: Nothing

be identical to:

- 33% Cycle: Red + Blue, together
- 67% Cycle: Nothing

Comment: No. Because the other has blue and the other one doesn't. Is that question perhaps missing something?

Comment: @Justme : Typo fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the alternating colors appear as mixed as if they were lit simultaneously?

Yes, and in fact this is how RGB addressable lights typically work. PWM is used to adjust the R, G and B intensity, meaning that except for the special case of "white" (all channels on equally), some of the colors are on while others are not:

[image: photograph of RGB LED bulb]

These will blend together to form a single color.

> 33% Cycle: Red only, then

> 33% Cycle: Blue only, then

That's purple.

> 33% Cycle: Red only, then

> 67% Cycle: Nothing

That's red. Red and purple are different colors so they're not identical. If you want to make them the same then both need blue to be present.